# Click on drop down and select second option using HP UFT

Tags: drop-down-menu, automation, hp-uft

I want click on drop down and select second option from it using HP UFT. so how can i do that.

Here is the link from where i want to use this

https://plus.google.com/communities/104621551449192390268

Click on "Share What's New..." and a box will appear.
Please refer the the attached screenshot for that

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use method *select*

```
objectSelectBox.Select "value from list"
```

But if you need to show that you can open the select box use those:

```
ObjectSelectBox.drag Drag , micNoCoordinate, micNoCoordinate, micCtrl
ObjectSelectBox.drop
```

in ObjectSelectBox - spy your own object